# problems with file I/O while running python 3.2 scripts in windows cmd, but not in IDLE

Tags: python

I am  a python noob, and am having problems running programs with open() functions  in cmd prompts. The code runs as expected in the python shell with IDLE, but everytime I open it by doubleclicking the icon coresponding to the script( I have .py associated with python), I get errors like

`what file test.txt (I entered input)

file 2 atest2.txt  (I entered intput)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\file_io\find_differences_in_files.py", line 3,
in <module>

    f=open(c,"r") # open c

IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'test.txt\r'`

Similar problems occur in multiple similar programs, but here is a sample of code( FYI, this code finds the first difference in two .txt files) that worked in IDLE but not in cmd. Anybody have any clue what is going wrong?

```
c=input("what file") # get file 1  
d=input("file 2") # get file 2  
f=open(c,"r") # open c   
g=open(d,"r") # open d  
p=f.readlines() # get every line of f   
q=g.readlines()   
i=0  
while i<len(p) and i<len(q):  
    if p[i]!=q[i]:   
        break # stop counting up  
    i+=1  
x=p[i] # store different line  
y=q[i] # store different line  
j=0  
while j<len(x) or i<len(y):       
    if x[j]!=y[j]:   
        break # stop counting up  
    j+=1  
print("The difference is in line %s column %s" % (i+1,j+1))  
c=input("press enter")
```

Comment: As an aside, the times of BASIC where variable names were only allowed to consist of one single character have passed. Make yourself happy by using somewhat more evocative names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling end-of-line characters correctly, and IDLE gives you the end-of-line in one format, while the cmd.exe sends another.

I suggest stripping whitespace from both ends of the input in this case.

Comment: thanks. I just stripped whitespace using c=c.strip(), and now it works in the cmd.